# Make Bootstrap dropdown from loop in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu that shows a list of items from a loop. I can view the source for the page and the loop is working, generating links, but the menu doesn't show anything but the title.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span data-bind="label">Select an Agency</span> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <% @results["RTT"]["AgencyList"]["Agency"].each do |agency| %>
      <li><a href ="/agencies/><%= agency['Name'] %>"</a></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks right... perhaps just missing a tag somewhere. Try to do it without the dynamic loop first

Answer (score 0):

I think your tags are just messed up. See how you are not closing your link opening tag properly? Try using a rails generated link like this: `<%=link_to agency['Name'], agency_path(id: agency['Name'])%>`.

Or if you want to keep your link the way you have it, just close it properly:

```
<li><a href="/agencies/<%= agency['Name'] %>"><%= agency['Name'] %></a></li>
```